# hibernate connection pool issue

Tags: hibernate, annotations, connection-pooling

For the life of me I cannot get rid of the Hibernate warning:

```
849 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)

849 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 20
```

I have looked at lots of other such postings but nothing helps. I will show my configuration and maybe someone can see what I cannot.

I am attempting to use C3P0 as the connection pool framework. I have the c3p0-0.9.1.jar file in the classpath (with other hibernate jars).

Here is a snippet of my persistence.xml file:

```
<property name="connection.provider_class"
             value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size"  value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size"  value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout"   value="5000" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate" value="false" />
```

I am using JPA annotations on my Entity Pojos. All of that is working great, meaning when i run my application, it runs fine, CRUD operations seem to work fine, etc (It is a pure-Java app. it is not running in an AppServer such as Tomcat or JBoss).

But I am very much bothered that I continue to see the "Using Hibernate built in Connection Pool" warning and no indication that C3P0 is running. For example, my log4j output shows tons of org.hibernate output at startup, but NO C3P0 output at all. Another indication it's not being used I would think.

In my application, one of the first things I do is create a static EntityManagerFactory (which is shared by an internal thread-pool; each worker-thread uses it to create an EntityManager to perform CRUD operations on concurrent commands, etc...). In a production environment, this application will experience heavy bursts of concurrent DB processing activity, so it is critical that I get the DB connection pool stuff right.

It is my understanding that the creation of the EntityManagerFactory is all that is needed to "start-up" the connection pool mechanism. Maybe this is incorrect? If so, what *should* I do within the application to initiate C3P0?

Advice/critique welcome.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you're using spring. If that's the case, then check this other question, which has a full working example on the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553890/configuring-the-built-in-c3p0-pooling-in-hibernate-using-spring

Comment: No, not using Spring. but I will check out your reference. thanks...

Comment: Just for the record, I finally got 3CP0 to come up. turns out that in my persistence.xml file, the property "connection.provider_class" needed to be specified as "hibernate.connection.provider_class". I also added a 3CP0.properties file to configure some c3p0-specific things, but that had nothing to do with my original failure.