# Tomcat JDBC connection pool configuration for hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

In my project I use following frameworks:

- Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool
- Hibernate
- Spring MVC

In JDBC connection pool configuration, I have set following properties:

- removeAbandoned - true
- removeAbandonedTimeout - 60 (default value)

As a result when time of hibernate transaction exceeds 60 seconds, happens

> java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection

exception and spring transactional AOP proxy of my service is unable to rollback database changes.

I have tested similar situation on JBOSS and I was getting transaction timeout exception instead of connection closed exception.

I changed value of removeAbandoned property to false and achieved JBOSS transaction similar behavior.

Please advice when using hibernate what is correct configuration (full JPA configuration) for apache connection pool to avoid such kind of problems ?

Comment: As far as I know, Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool is not used in "real world" applications, what is actually used is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553890/configuring-the-built-in-c3p0-pooling-in-hibernate-using-spring. I think you better switch to that, unless you just wanted to understand out of curiousity how Tomcat JDBC pooling works.

Comment: Closed connection usually thrown at database level. Can you check if RDBMS closing connection after 1 minute?